# Does CQ5 store modification list(history) of crx?

Tags: aem, apache-felix, audit, crx, rollout

Sometime someone want to change inside something crx directly on environment.

Often it is a cause of unworking state of environment. And often enough hard to find the cause of the problem. And I think it is will be helpful if cq5 crx will have audit log. something like this.

```
12.12.12 21:03 /etc/blueprints/geometrixx was removed  [rollout]
...
```

maybe CQ5 has  something like this already?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these changes to the repositories are made using **crxde lite[/crx/de/index.jsp]** or **content explorer [/crx/explorer/browser/index.jsp]** , there is an indirect way to find out who did it.

The data can be fetched by looking into two different logs **request.log** and **audit.log** [these files can be found at **\crx-quickstart\logs** folder ]

The modifications to nodes are **POST** requests. These are logged in **request.log** , the path of the request will only show the interface used or to root node. If you search the time stamp of the POST in **audit.log** you can find which user did a **GET** request.

This is not direct way, nor will it tell more of the changes except for which user read the node at the time of the **POST** .